# Conversion of kilometers to miles

Tags: python, function, variables, input, output

This is a program that converts kilometers to miles however, every time I run it there is no line asking for an input, as it is supposed to, instead it is always blank.

Here is the code:

```
KILOMETERS_TO_MILES =float(0.6214)

def main():
    Distance = input("please input the distance in kilometers to wish to convert:"))
    showMiles(Distance)

def showmiles(Distance):
    miles = Distance * KILOMETERS_TO_MILES
    print=("Conversion of ", Distance,"kilometers to miles: ", miles, "miles")

main()
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation in the question.  As posted, this cannot possibly be valid Python code.

Comment: If you're using the code shown, you should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: Syntax error, no updates since weeks ... this should actually be closed ... and thrown out.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
KILOMETERS_TO_MILES = 0.621371

def show_miles(Distance):
    miles = Distance * KILOMETERS_TO_MILES
    print('Conversion of {} kilometers to miles: {} miles'.format(Distance, miles))

def main():
    Distance = float(input("please input the distance in kilometers you wish to convert: "))
    show_miles(Distance)

main()
```

Your original code had several problems:

```
KILOMETERS_TO_MILES =float(0.6214)

def main():
    # You have an extra closing ')' on the next line
    Distance = input("please input the distance in kilometers to wish to convert: "))
    showMiles(Distance)  # this showMiles has an upper case 'M'

def showmiles(Distance):  # this showmiles has a lower case 'm'
    miles = Distance * KILOMETERS_TO_MILES
    # You have an = sign on the next line that shouldn't be there
    print=("Conversion of ", Distance,"kilometers to miles: ", miles, "miles")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like part of the problem comes from your third line. I have noticed you have two closing brackets '))' yet you only have one opeining '('.
'..

Comment: As noted by the other answer (among other issues) ~7 months ago.